# How to real-time display a number from a running log file or terminal

Tags: terminal, logs, real-time

I have a CNC and the software runs from a terminal. I would like to catch the current Z axis depth in real-time to display it.
The information I need is shown in the terminal as well as in the log file during the run (G1 Z-0.05) however this might be in the middle of the line with other information. Is there a way to catch the latest Z depth? I think I can manage the display part, so I'm interested in how I can catch the changing Z to always have the current value.
Thanks in advance.

The software is started with python main.py. In the GUI i run the cut. The commands sent to an arduino are visible in the terminal and also written to a log.txt. Can I intercept the terminal or is it easier to tail the log?

Sample output From the terminal: "Sending: G0 Z0.5" From the logfile: Sent: G1 Z-0.05 F30

What I would like to catch is the values behind Z/z positive and negatine

Comment: Please post some sample output and specify the part you want to capture.  Do you run a command to start your CNC?

Comment: The software is started with python main.py. In the GUI i run the cut. The commands sent to an arduino are visible in the terminal and also written to a log.txt. Can I intercept the terminal or is it easier to tail the log?

Comment: You can probably do either but in order for us to help you need to post some sample output.

Comment: From the terminal: "Sending: G0 Z0.5" From the logfile: Sent: G1 Z-0.05 F30

Answer (score 2):

Given example input of:

```
Sent: G1 Z-0.05 F30
```

This should capture the information you desire:

```
grep -o 'Z[^ ]*' inputfile
Z-0.05
```

Or, to capture in real-time:

```
tail -f inputfile | grep -o 'Z[^ ]*'
```

Comment: `grep --line-buffered` for faster response.